# Подключение к серверу Openvpn с сертификатом из приложения

Tags: ubuntu, golang, openvpn

Интересует данный вопрос, у меня настроено VPN-соединение на Ubuntu по сертификату,локально запускаю телеграмм бота, существует ли способ, подключения к vpn-серверу не посредственно из самого приложения. Яп Go.

Comment: Ну это в прогу должна быть встроена другая прога. В данном случае - впн. Так что да, возможно.

Comment: Есть примеры использования, к примеру https://github.com/txthinking/brook/blob/master/vpn.go